# Run a query consisting of subqueries only

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that only consists of sub queries, But I cannot run it I get an SQL error, What is the correct Syntax to run query consisting of sub queries only...?

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'totalNumOfCustomers'
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND regTime < '2012-01-01'

SELECT COUNT(id) AS 'totalNumOfCustomersPerMonth' 
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND regTime >='2012-01-01' 
AND regTime < '2012-02-01'

SELECT COUNT(positions.id) AS 'totalPositions',
ROUND(SUM(amount),2) - ROUND(SUM(payout),2) AS 'grossIncome'  
FROM positions  
LEFT JOIN customers ON positions.customerId = customers.id 
WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' 
AND date < '2012-02-01' 
AND customers.isDemo=0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND status != 'canceled'
```

I am running this in WorkBench, The error message is this:

```
Error Code: 1064. You Have an error in your SQL syntax
```

Comment: Please include the error message in the question.

Comment: Care to share the error message with us? How/from what are you executing this? What you have posted is 3 queries, there are no sub-queries. Please edit and add a tag that identifies the database system your using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
select 

(SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND regTime < '2012-01-01') as totalNumOfCustomers,

(SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND regTime >='2012-01-01' 
AND regTime < '2012-02-01') as totalNumOfCustomersPerMonth,

(SELECT COUNT(positions.id)
FROM positions  
LEFT JOIN customers ON positions.customerId = customers.id 
WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' 
AND date < '2012-02-01' 
AND customers.isDemo=0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND status != 'canceled') as totalPositions,

(SELECT ROUND(SUM(amount),2) - ROUND(SUM(payout),2)
FROM positions  
LEFT JOIN customers ON positions.customerId = customers.id 
WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' 
AND date < '2012-02-01' 
AND customers.isDemo=0 
AND customers.isLead=0 
AND status != 'canceled') as grossIncome;
```

Comment: Now I get this ERROR Code 1241. Operand Should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Ah yes, the third query returns two values, so can't be written as a subquery before `as totalPositions`. I'll edit it.

Comment: Perfect, So I cannot have one subquery returning two values in any circumstances, Happy to learn something new :) Thank you

Comment: Would up vote your answer as well but not enough Points

Comment: I suspect the cross join by Gordon Linoff is at least as good, if not better, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you get error, because there is no `;` ant the end of each query. No error message, so just guessing

Answer (score 0):

You can run these queries by putting them in the `from` clause and combining them using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) totalNumOfCustomers
        FROM customers 
        WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
        AND customers.isLead=0 
        AND regTime < '2012-01-01'
       ) t1 CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT COUNT(id) as totalNumOfCustomersPerMonth
        FROM customers 
        WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
        AND customers.isLead=0 
        AND regTime >='2012-01-01' 
        AND regTime < '2012-02-01'
       ) t2 CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT COUNT(positions.id) AS totalPositions,
               ROUND(SUM(amount),2) - ROUND(SUM(payout),2) AS grossIncome
        FROM positions LEFT JOIN
             customers
             ON positions.customerId = customers.id 
        WHERE date >= '2012-01-01' 
        AND date < '2012-02-01' 
        AND customers.isDemo=0 
        AND customers.isLead=0 
        AND status <> 'canceled'
      ) t3;
```

Note:  don't use single quotes for column and table aliases.  That will lead to confusion.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.

Comment: Now I get this Error Message: Error Code: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

The two first queries you can easily express as one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when regTime < '2012-01-01' end ) AS totalNumOfCustomers
     , COUNT(case when >='2012-01-01' AND regTime < '2012-02-01' end ) AS  totalNumOfCustomersPerMonth
FROM customers 
WHERE customers.isDemo =0 
  AND customers.isLead=0 ;
```

As others have suggested you can then use a cross join to take the third query into play